# Empty body has bigger width than screen

Tags: html, css

Straight to the point, chrome says that my body has bigger width than screen size:

[image]

I simply cannot understand why this is happening, I saw that happening when I had the rest of the page developed, and I deleted element by element until I saw that even with empty body I've this issue.
I tried box-sizing, width vw instead of 100%, and the rest of answers that i've find.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: It's a Flask project using Jinja2, it's pretty weird syntax for someone who didn't work with that before, it's just about an empty body, I tried now <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />, still same issue

Answer (score 1):

The zoom was the problem, I had 90% zoom set on chrome!

Answer (score 0):

if it is not a problem related to some css rule of the HTML tag, I would try an approach similar to this .. :)

```
body{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've found what was the problem, I posted the answer.

Comment: Hahaha! I understand! XD